# How to load firestore data on frontend (react native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on React Native App.  Data from firestore is getting load and showing in my console but not on frontend. I have similar code below.

```
state={
record:[],
}

componentdidmount(){
this.displaydata();
}

displaydata =()=>{

Firebase query here//
//data gets load and stored in userrecords array below.

const userrecords=[];
userrecords.push(data); // data from firestore
console.log("User data":userrecords); // it displays it to console like below.
     --------------------
 Console : 
    Array[
       Object{
         "user":"ABC"
         "age":25
    },
    ]
    Array[
       Object{
         "user":"XYZ"
         "age":30
    },
    ]
    ----------------------
this.setState({record:userrecords})

}
```

To load on frontend below is my code: But its not loading on frontend. What is the possible reason for that.

```
 render(){
    return(
   <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       {this.state.record ? (
        <>
         <Text>Data from firebase firestore</Text>
         <FlatList
         style={{ flex: 1 }}
         data={this.state.record}
         keyExtractor={(key, index) => key + index}
         renderItem={(itemData) => {
           {console.log(itemData.item.age)}  // it display all data on console.
           return <Text>{itemData.item.age}</Text>; // it display last array data item only.
         }}
         />
       </>
       ) : (
       <View
         style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
       >
         <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
       </View>
     )}
     </View>
    );
    }
```

My console:
[ConsoleData_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kVQd.png)
[..Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6itC.png)

Comment: You can use FlatList for map your data

Comment: Hi @RuchiraSwarnapriya . Can you guide me in answer section how to write and display my example in flatlist, that would be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Data from your firestore looks like

```
[
    [
      {
        user: "ABC",
        age: "25",
      },
    ],
    [
      {
       user:"XYZ",
       age:"30",
      }
    ],
]
```

**By using FlatList**. Don't forget to import `ActivityIndicator`

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";   
... 
... 
render(){
    return(
       <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       {this.state.record ? (
        <>
         <Text>Data from firebase firestore</Text>
         <FlatList
         style={{ flex: 1 }}
         data={this.state.record}
         keyExtractor={(key, index) => key + index}
         renderItem={(itemData) => {
           return <Text>{itemData.item[0].age}</Text>;
         }}
         />
       </>
       ) : (
       <View
         style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
       >
         <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
       </View>
     )}
     </View>
    );
   }
```

Comment: Hi Ragul. I have added return keyword, now its returning only last value of array on screen. That is age 30 (as mentioned in example). Please guide further. Thanks

Comment: Wrap Text component inside a View but this is not the best practice use FlatList

Comment: Thanks @RagulCs. Can you guide me with how to write current code into FlatList. I have tried but couldn't do it properly. TIA

Comment: Thanks dear for helping. I have updated the code. Now getting error: " Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'ítemData.item[0].age') ".

Comment: Then add a check condition, Do check now

Comment: Still same error. Please check my question i have updated and added images of data and error. Last Line you can find images named consoledata and error

Comment: How data is retrieved from firestore (Array or Object)

Comment: i have added image for console data you can check in my question last line. If I console I get: Array[object{ name:"ABC",age:25}],Array[object{ name:"XYZ",age:30}]

Comment: The code works fine for the data structure which I have used (NOTE: I'm assuming firestore returns array which includes nested array)

Comment: Data i receive from firebase is like: Object{"user":"ABC", "age":25}. Then i put it into an array then update my state(setState) with array. Then i want to load my state into render. Please help ragul i am counting on you.

Comment: Then try `<Text>{itemData.item.age}</Text>`

Comment: Now I am not getting any error and also no data is displaying on screen. I can see only this : <Text>Data from firebase firestore</Text> (showing msg inside this component only)

Comment: if i console.log(itemdata.item.age) inside render comment it displays age in console.

Comment: No it should render Text. Can you please say is this a single screen or importing this component in some other component? Try removing all styles

Comment: From previous method (map) it was displaying last item of array on screen. Its single screen.

Comment: And also from FlatList its also displaying last array item only. but in console it displays all items.

Comment: @d5v5lop create a sandbox project

Comment: Can i share my screen?

Comment: Basically the problem is my state is adding multiple arrays of data instead of adding multiple objects in state. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612584/how-to-display-state-in-flatlist-reactnative-react . Please look into this. Thanks