# How to display state in FlatList ReactNative/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have record state in my react native app.

```
state{
    record:[] //some data inside, When i console my state it looks like this:
}
```

Console output of my record state:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 23,
    },
]
Array[
 Object {
    "name": "xyz",
    "age": 27,
    },
]
```

When i render it through FlatList it shows only first item of array that is name abc and age 23. While it should also load 2 array item in state, which is name xyz and age 27. below is the code for output of state.

```
displaydata(){
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users').where('age', '>=', 21)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {

                querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                    const urecords = [];
                    const udata = documentSnapshot.data();
                    urecords.push(udata);
                   
                    this.setState({ record: [...urecords] })

                });
            });
    }
}
render(){
    return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    {this.state.record ? (
    <>
    <Text>Data from firebase firestore</Text>
          <FlatList
                 style={{ flex: 1 }}
                 data={this.state.record}
                 keyExtractor={(key, index) => key + index}
                 renderItem={(itemData) => {

                     console.log(this.state.record); // it displays all data of state in console as i have consoled above
                     return <Text>{itemData.item.name}{itemData.item.age}</Text>; // it displays first array data(item) only, which is abc and 23

                  }
               }
          />
    </>
       ) : (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
         <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
      </View>
     )}
    </View>
    );

 }
```

I want to load complete state on my screen.

Comment: Does your state contain an array of array ?

Comment: I think yes, please check my code i have added some code.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have 2 different arrays inside this.state.record.
Try to spread your data arrays inside state or combine them into 1 union array. Your this.state.record should look like this

```
state = {
  records: [
    { name: 'xyz', age: '23', },
    { name: 'abc', age: '27', },
  ]
```

This will show you list with 2 objects

```
console.log('STATE RECORDS', this.state.records)

// console.log output
STATE RECORDS [
  { name: 'xyz', age: '23', },
  { name: 'abc', age: '27', },
]
```

Comment: Hi. Please check i have added more code and guide me how to do this.

Comment: how to do this inside displaydata() ? Kindly guide

Comment: Feels like you spreading docs that contains array inside of it. You need to map property which is array again inside doc that you spreading from doc.data()
This should be like this.setState({ ...urecords.${name_of_your_array_property} })

Comment: Yes, how to overcome this? I am new please guide

Comment: You means this.setState({ record : [...urecords.${name,age}] }) .

Comment: Try this this.setState({ records: [...urecords.map(item => item) ] })

Comment: Would be better if you refactor your querySnapshot like querySnapshot.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data() }))

Comment: Tried this this.setState({ records: [...urecords.map(item => item) ] }). This return empty State on console like this [].

Comment: still same output . console shows [] . if i console.log("Here" +JSON.stringfy(this.state.record));

Comment: Hey @devilcore . I got my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616072/15336038

Sharing this for knowledge :)