# How to load complete state in FlatList Component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have record state in my react native app.

```
state{
    record:[],
    //initially empty, then i setState in displaydata(), then state looks like this in console 
}
```

Console output of my record state:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 23,
    },
]
Array[
 Object {
    "name": "xyz",
    "age": 27,
    },
]
```

Below is displaydata function and when render it through FlatList it shows only first item of array that is name abc and age 23. While it should also load 2nd array item in state, which is name xyz and age 27. below is the code for output of state.

```
displaydata(){
        firebase.firestore()
            .collection('users').where('age', '>=', 21)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {

                querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                    const urecords = [];
                    const udata = documentSnapshot.data();
                    urecords.push(udata);
                   
                    this.setState({ record: [...urecords] })

                });
            });
    }
}
render(){
    return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    {this.state.record ? (
    <>
    <Text>Data from firebase firestore</Text>
          <FlatList
                 style={{ flex: 1 }}
                 data={this.state.record}
                 keyExtractor={(key, index) => key + index}
                 renderItem={(itemData) => {

                     console.log(this.state.record); // it displays all data of state in console as i have consoled above
                     return <Text>{itemData.item.name}{itemData.item.age}</Text>; // it displays first array data(item) only, which is abc and 23

                  }
               }
          />
    </>
       ) : (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
         <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
      </View>
     )}
    </View>
    );

 }
```

I want to load complete state on my screen as i have in my console. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding your state here:

`this.setState({ record: [...urecords] })`

Instead do the following:

`this.setState({ record: [...this.state.record,...urecords]})`

First we copy the previous entries, then we add the new ones.